# Unable to run neo4j 1.9.5 server on DB 2.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am trying to run community server 1.9.5 on pre-existing DB (2.0).
Its working on Windows but on ubuntu its always giving this issue.
Your help would be highly appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnableToUpgradeException: Not all store files match the version required for successful upgrade
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:82) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.attemptUpgrade(StoreUpgrader.java:67) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.tryToUpgradeStores(StoreFactory.java:113) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:96) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:240) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491) ~[neo4j-kernel-1.9.5.jar:1.9.5]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't start 1.9 neo on a 2.0 store. The file is different, and it can't automatically change itself back. It has space for labels, etc.--much different format that would require a lot of conversion. Why do you want to start 1.9 on a 2.0 store?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wes for your answer.running 1.9 neo on 2.0 store was creating an issue as you mentioned.
We did not want to do that but since couldnt find 2.0 neo thought 1.9 would be compatible with 2.0.We changed the neo to 2.0 and it worked.